# Problems with resolution in Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, debian, resolution

I can not get a higher resolution higher than 1024x768 inside VirtualBox using Debian 8 OS, no matter what I do: Installing VirtualBox Guest Additions, restarting VirtualBox, re-Installing the OS, reinstalling VirtualBox and OS, rebooting main computer then reinstalling everything again and virtual OS. All other OSs work fine except this OS and two others. This OS does not seem to want to go higher than 1024x768 resolution.

I have gone to hundreds and hundreds of websites to find solutions and even tried most of them. And nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you sure guest additions successfully installed on yours? I just installed Debian 8 on virtualbox and had the same problem you are having. Tried installing guest additions a couple times but it kept failing. Once I finally got it installed and rebooted the machine, I was able to change the resolution to 1920x1080.

Comment: (1) You say, "all other OS's work fine except this OS," but also, "There are 2 other OS's this happens to."  These appear to be contradictory.  (2) If most OSs work correctly and a few do not, why do you believe that it's Oracle's fault?  (3) If you're unhappy with VirtualBox, you can return it to Oracle and ask for your money back.  Oh, wait…